# ¿Que significa el parametro num_segments al recibir datos desde la API Google Fit RecordHistory?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api

Estoy trabajando con la API de Google Fit y no se exactamente que siginifica el parámetro que devuelve la API Google Fit RecordHistory "num_segments",  aquí tengo un ejemplo de los datos devueltos:

```
Data returned for Data type: com.google.activity.summary
Data point:
Type: com.google.activity.summary
Start: 25 oct. 2017 9:21:24
End: 25 oct. 2017 13:21:24
Field: activity Value: 3
Field: duration Value: 14400000
Field: num_segments Value: 1

Data returned for Data type: com.google.activity.summary
Data point:
Type: com.google.activity.summary
Start: 25 oct. 2017 13:21:24
End: 25 oct. 2017 16:34:12
Field: activity Value: 3
Field: duration Value: 11568153
Field: num_segments Value: 2
```

En la documentación de Google lo define como :

> Número de segmentos en una actividad concreta durante un intervalo de tiempo.

Pero no termino de entender a qué se refiere con el número de segmentos.

Comment: Mira este [enlace](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions#insert_activity_segments). *Si entiendo bien* número de segmentos son la cantidad de actividades hechas en la rutina.

Answer (score 0):

creo que significa que durante el periodo de tiempo comprendido:
Start: 25 oct. 2017 13:21:24
End: 25 oct. 2017 16:34:12

Has realizado la actividad de tipo 3 (activity Value: 3) dos veces.

En el fragmento anterior: 
Start: 25 oct. 2017 9:21:24
End: 25 oct. 2017 13:21:24

solo la has realizado una vez.